# creating a sum tree from leafs

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

ok i am given a bunch of leafs 10,9,7,8 and i need to create a sum tree from them as such
[image]

i need to find the sum of what is circled.

the problem is really a weight problem where i can choose two elements at a time to add them and their combined weight is the work done to combine the elements and i have to keep doing this till all the weights are combined while doing the minimum amount of work but i have turned it into this because i think this is the way to solve it.

is this the best way to solve this problem or is there a better way?

what would be the fastest way to create this tree and calculate the sum of those nodes?

Comment: If this is a homework question you should tag it as such

Comment: not homework its form a coding competition on techgig

Comment: Make a recursive method that takes m pairs of numbers (with 2m a power of two), calculate the sum of each pair and passes them as the argument of the next recursion step. The idea needs to be tweaked accordingly to your specific needs (e.g. you have to exclude from the total sum the initial values), but it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The greedy solution:

1. Put all leaves in a priority queue (minimum weight comes out first).
2. While the queue contains more than one tree, pull out the two least-weight trees, join them and insert the joint tree into the queue.
3. When the queue contains only a single tree, that is your solution.

### The greedy solution works:

Given any binary tree built from the leaves, each leaf contributes `depth*weight` to the total work/cost. (Where the depth of a leaf is the length of the path from the root to the leaf, e.g. in

```
   18
  /  \
  3   15
/  \ /  \
1  2 4  11
       / \
       5  6
```

the leaves 1, 2, and 4 have depth 2, the leaves 5 and 6 have depth 3.)

So for any given shape of the tree, the smallest total cost is obtained when the lightest leaves are the deepest. Therefore a minimum cost tree is reached when the first step is joining the two lightest leaves to a new tree.

When some leaves have already been joined, the total cost of building the tree is (cost so far) + (cost of building cheapest tree considering the non-singleton trees as leaves).

So in the minimum cost tree, by the reasoning above, the two lightest "leaves" must be at the deepest level, hence can be joined to form a new subtree.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [stack machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine). Push the leaves until the stack has 2 elements. Pop those elements, add (sub, mult, div, etc.) them, and push the result. Continuously do that until the input has no more elements. The final result is on top of the stack. This algorithm does arithmetic in the same order the sum tree would do it.

```
code                stack
--------------------------
push 10             10$        
push 9              9, 10$     

pop a               10$
pop b               $
push a+b            19$

push 7              7, 19$
push 8              8, 7, 19$

pop a               7, 19$
pop b               19$
push a+b            15, 19$

pop a               19$
pop b               $
push a+b            34$

done                34$
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation using Java

```
public static int sumTree(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int oldVal = node.getData();
    node.setData(sumTree(node.getLeft()) + sumTree(node.getRight()));

    return oldVal + node.getData();
}
```

Here is the test case

```
@Test
public void sumTreeTest() {
    BinaryTreeNode<Integer> bt = BinaryTreeUtil.<Integer>fromInAndPostOrder(new Integer[]{8,-2,-4,10,7,6,5}, new Integer[]{8,-4,-2,7,5,6,10});
    BinaryTreeUtil.sumTree(bt);
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    BinaryTreeUtil.printInOrder(bt, result);
    assertThat(result.toArray(new Integer[0]), equalTo(new Integer[]{0, 4, 0, 20, 0, 12, 0}));
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result.toArray()));
}
```